# Creating a log file in embedded VC++ using Win32 API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Can any one help me on how to create a log file in embedded VC++ using the Win32 API?

Right now, I'm trying to create multiple file on WinCE PC. For this I need to provide a log file whether a file is created or not. I am able to create a message on console but I need to store that message in a text file instead of displaying for each and every file.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly answered in [High performance logging library for embedded applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838603/high-performance-logging-library-for-embedded-applications) ?

Ok, I read your question again - in case you cannot pull in a library, you may want to read this one instead: [how do I write a logger class with cout style interface (logger << "Error: " << val << endl;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235560/how-do-i-write-a-logger-class-with-cout-style-interface-logger-error-v)